# Does containerization always lead to cpu, ram and storage cost savings as compared to VMs?

Tags: docker, containers

Being a naive in the world of containers, and after reading a lot of literature online, I was wondering if someone could render some guidance.

I wanted to know if containers always lead to cost savings in terms of cpu, memory and storage when compared with the same application running inside a VM.

I can think of a scenario when it won’t when the scaleset in case of VM running inside an orchestrator like kubernetes is a high number leading to more consumption of compute.

I was wondering what is the general understanding here

Comment: "always" is a strong word. I guess using a container is more efficient in most cases, but there might be edge-cases where this does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Containerization is not about cost savings in terms of CPU/RAM/Storage, but a lot more.

When an app gets deployed on a VM, you need to have specific tools like Ansible/Chef/Puppet to optimize deployments, and you also need additional tools to monitor the load to increase/decrease the number of VMs running, you also need additional tools to provide WideIP support across the running services in case of a REST API, and the list goes on.

With Containers running on Kubernetes, you have all these features built in to some extent, and when you deploy Servicemesh framework like Istio, you get additional features which add lot of value with minimum effort including Circuit Breakers, retries, authentication, etc.